# Winter Bash Hat Appears in Post

Tags: discussion, bug, winter-bash

Why does my hat sometimes appear random on the website?

I have observed that when I reload the page the hat is first at a wrong position and then it will correct its position to my profile picture.

But sometimes it is stuck and is twice on the site.

Have someone else observed this behavior?

[image]

Comment: related https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/358065/347191

Comment: Yeah, we're all seeing this. This bug has been noted by many different users, and reported multiple times on the global Meta: https://meta.stackexchange.com. I'm marking this as a duplicate of the one bug report for this that has been posted on this site. It's all the same bug, even though it may manifest in multiple places. The developers are aware of it.

Comment: Okay well, thanks for the answer.